# How to get vim-latex's \cite completion to pick up the .bib file from the directory below?

Tags: biblatex, vim, vim-latex

I'm using the [Classic Thesis Latex template](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home) which provides the Chapters in a separate folder in relation to the 'root' file and the .bib file. When editing the chapters in Vim I would like to use the  completion feature for references but as the .bib file sits in the folder below in relation to the file I'm editing, vim is not able to locate it. So I was wondering how I could get it to pick up the references from the .bib located at a lower level than the current folder?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the option you need to set is [Tex_BIBINPUTS](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-latex-completion.html#Tex_BIBINPUTS). If you have modelines enabled, you can probably add a modeline in the specific files of your thesis to setup this variable, or you can set it in your `.vimrc` :

```
let g:Tex_BIBINPUTS="path/to/bibfolder/"
```