# Vim Latex Suite unable to find .bib file if not explicitly specified in the current file

Tags: citing, vim, vim-latex

I'm using Neovim and the Latex Suite for Latex Documents. When I put all the code in a single file, cite completion using F9 is working like a charm. However, if I split my source file using `\include` it stops working. Instead of showing a list of possible citations, insertion mode is entered. Following https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/135 I checked that Python was available and used for cite completion:

```
:echo Tex_HasPython
3
:echo Tex_UsePython()
1
:echo Tex_GetVarValue('Tex_UsePython')
1
:echo Tex_GetVarValue('Tex_UseCiteCompletionVer2')
1
```

The log file created using `let g:Tex_Debug = 1` and `let g:Tex_DebugLog = "vim-latex-suite.log"` shows no bibfiles found:

```
view : Tex_Complete: s:type = cite, typeoption =
view : :Tex_Complete: using s:prefix =
view : :Tex_FindBibFiles:
proj : texproject.vim: catching LatexSuiteFileType event
env : envmacros.vim: Catching LatexSuiteFileType event
comp : compiler.vim: Catching LatexSuiteFileType event
fold : folding.vim: catching LatexSuiteFileType
brak : brackets.vim: Catching LatexSuiteFileType event
view : texviewer.vim: Catching LatexSuiteFileType event
main : main.vim: Catching LatexSuiteFileType event
pack : packages.vim: Catching LatexSuiteFileType event
pack : +Tex_pack_updateall
view : :Tex_FindBibFiles: returning []
view : :Tex_StartCiteCompletion: No bibfiles found.
view : :Tex_SwitchToInsertMode: %
```

Following [How to get vim-latex's \cite completion to pick up the .bib file from the directory below?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314710/how-to-get-vim-latexs-cite-completion-to-pick-up-the-bib-file-from-the-direct), `g:Tex_BIBINPUTS` was set to both a directory containing a bibfile which is usable when explicitly mentioned or the file itself but is not picked up in both cases. I cannot set the bibliography in each file as this is only possible in the preamble.

MWE.tex:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

```
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\title{MWE for dysfunctional cite completion}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  Here completion works \cite{}
  \include{cite}
\end{document}
```

cite.tex:

```
Here the completion should work but doesn't \cite{}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@report{europeanroadsafetyobservatoryTrafficSafetyBasic2012,
  title = {Traffic {{Safety Basic Facts}} 2012 - {{Cyclists}}},
  author = {{European Road Safety Observatory}},
  date = {2012},
  keywords = {Partly Processed,Safety},
  file = {/home/mbeeking/Zotero/storage/3RLBIXIE/bfs2012_dacota-swov-cyclists.pdf}
}
```

In the MWE.tex file the cite completion is working as expected:
[image: Cite completion working in MWE]

In the cite.tex file insertion mode is entered:
[image: Cite completion not working in other file]

Comment: Can you try using `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography` (which is deprecated for `biblatex`)? Does it work if you use `\input` instead of `\include`? Does setting a `.latexmain` help?

Comment: I found a different solution as posted below and thus will not try this, but thanks nonetheless!

Comment: My suggestion was to set a `.latexmain` file... like your answer...

Comment: My appologies, you are absolutely correct, I just found the answer before reading your comment and than appear to not have read it thoroughly. I have edited my answer to credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr:

As also suggested by [Dai Bowen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/106162/dai-bowen) in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/106162/dai-bowen), for using the Vim Latex Suite with multi-file projects one should mark the master file following https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html#latex-project-example

---

As ever so often I stumbled upon the answer just after posting the question but decided to leave it here for reference. If you have set up a multi-file project you need to mark the main file for Latex Suite. Let's say you have document.tex including several other files, possibly in subdirectories. Then you need to create a (possibly empty, I used `touch`) file called document.tex.latexmain in the same directory as document.tex. Latex Suite will search your file system going upwards from the file you're currently working on for such a file and pull things like the bibliography from there. See https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html#latex-project-example for further information.

Comment: This is the answer for me and I will accept it next week when I'm back at work